# Inciting fear in the public

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law

On a recent foreign prank show the following scenario took place.

A group are dressed in realistic [Hazmat suits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazmat_suit).
The group are scanning an area with fake [radiation detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_detector).

The detectors are set to emit a sound that indicates danger, more specifically high levels of radiation.

When the detectors emit the sound, the group run away making a scene to ensure the surrounding public take notice and react.

All of this being a façade to purposely incite fear in to the public.

I am sure that this wouldn't be tolerated in most countries, and would be breaking the law.

Which laws would cover this behaviour?

Comment: This would probably be public nuisance, in common law - there's quite probably statutes which outlaw this, I'll need to have a look.

Comment: It's probably going to be a mischief related crime. Something along the lines like that, or of Creating a public disturbance.